# Convert an image to matrix

Tags: java, image, matrix

I'm trying to convert an simple image to an matrix M*N, where M and N are the width and the heigth of my image.
But at this point i don't understand the best way to work out the steps.

There is my code at this moment:

```
  public double[][] img2matriz(BufferedImage bi){
    double[][] C;
    for(int i=0;i<bi.getHeight();i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0;j<bi.getWidth();j++)
        {
            C[i][j]
        }
    }     
}
```

In [i] and [j] i want to put the values of the matrix RGB respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
C[i][j] = bi.getRGB(i, j);
```

the `getRGB()` method returns an integer, which can be bit-masked to give you the individual components.  It would be more appropriate if C was a integer array, not double.

Answer (score 0):

create a class :

```
    class RGB {
        private :
           float r;
           float g;
           float b;

            RGB(float rr , float gg , float bb) : r(rr) ,g(gg), b(bb){}
        public:
... member functions
    }
```

and use it as array of object .

Answer (score 0):

**First** : initialize your array Like this :

```
double[][] C = new double[bi.getHeight()][bi.getWidth()];
```

**Second** : get the `RGB` from your Image and put it in your array, Like this:

```
C[i][j] = bi.getRGB(i, j);
```

and if you want to get the 3 channels in your image`(RED-GREEN-BLUE)` : You can do this :

```
int red = (C[i][j]>> 16) & 0x000000FF;
int green = (C[i][j]>>8 ) & 0x000000FF;
int blue = (C[i][j]) & 0x000000FF;
```